# Splitting one column into multiple based on data or line break

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm working in python, and trying to use pandas to split one column into multiple based on either the presence of date or line break. Here is the structure of my data:

| Column |
| --- |
| 1/1/2020 |
| AST: 100 |
| ALT: 200 |
|  |
| 1/2/2020 |
| AST: 200 |
| ALT: 300 |
|  |
| 1/3/2020 |
| AST:100 |
| ALT:200 |

My final result I expect to be something like

| 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2020 | 1/3/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AST:100 | AST:200 | AST:100 |
| ALT:200 | ALT:300 | ALT:200 |

Any suggestions would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Add the code that you have tested and make sure that all the log errors that you are facing have to be written also to help others to have a clear idea what 's your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I created a `new` column to group date and values below that. Afterwards using `groupby` and `concat` I got result you expected.

```
df["new"] =pd.to_datetime(df["Column"],errors="coerce").notna().cumsum()
datas=[]
for key,value in df.groupby("new"):
    datas.append(pd.DataFrame(value).reset_index(drop=True))
df=pd.concat(datas,axis=1).filter(like="Column")
df.columns=df.iloc[0]
df=df[1:]
print(df)
```

returns

```
    1/1/2020    1/2/2020    1/3/2020
1   AST: 100    AST: 200    AST:100
2   ALT: 200    ALT: 300    ALT:200
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` if you set up some helper columns first:

```
(df.assign(group=df['Column'].isna().shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
   .assign(index=lambda d: d.groupby('group').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='group', columns='index', values='Column')
   .set_index(0)                          # set the dates as index
   .T                                     # transpose back to desired format
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None) # you can set custom names here
   .iloc[:-1]                             # remove NaNs in last position
)
```

output:

```
   1/1/2020  1/2/2020 1/3/2020
1  AST: 100  AST: 200  AST:100
2  ALT: 200  ALT: 300  ALT:200
```

Comment: Perhaps this would work for the line breaks. But doesn't work when there are no line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution in case the amount of dates and sub data is unknown.

```
import pandas as pd
infile = open("new2.txt")
dict = {}
indexx = 0
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n\r')
    if "/" in line:
        date = line
        if indexx == 0: dict = {date:[]}
        else: dict[date] = []
    if ":" in line:
        dict[date].append(line)
    if line == "":
        indexx += 1
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
df.to_csv("new22.txt", index = False)
```